# foreach pipe in multipleline string

Tags: powershell, foreach, format

Here is my code:

```
$collection1 = "1","2","3","4"
"
collection1:
$($collection1 | % {$_})
"
```

The output is:

```
collection1:

1 2 3 4
```

However, I'm expecting:

```
collection1:
1
2
3
4
```

So I changed my code to:

```
"
$($collection1 | % {$_ + "`n"})
"
```

Now, it shows:

```
collection1:
1
 2
 3
 4
```

Why there is always an extra space in the front of each line?

Any way to remove them?

I tried to use `Trim()`, `[String]::Format()`, and few other ways, none is working as expected.

Comment: Which version of powershell are you using? I get the output you want using your exact query.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer... For anyone's interest...

```
$collection1 = "1","2","3","4"

$body = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()

foreach($item in $collection1)
{
    [void]$body.Append($item+"`n")
}

"
collection1:
$body
"
```

Answer (score 0):

`$collection1 | % {$_}` takes the array `$collection1` and outputs each of its elements, which gives you the exact same thing you strated with: an array of the elements of `$collection1`. Using a subexpression to put that array into a string auto-converts the array to a string, so that it can be inserted into the outer string. In PowerShell this array-to-string conversion is done by joining the array elements with the `$OFS` character (Output Field Separator, by default a single space), which for your example produces the string "1 2 3 4".

The simplest way of getting the result you expect is to convert the array to a formatted string yourself:

```
"
collection1:
$($collection1 | Out-String)
"
```

The `Out-String` cmdlet converts array input to a single string by joining all input strings with newlines. Alternatively join the array yourself:

```
"
collection1:
$($collection1 -join "`n")
"
```

You could also (temporarily) modify `$OFS` and use the variable directly:

```
$OFS_bak = $OFS
$OFS = "`n"
"
collection1:
$collection1
"
$OFS = $OFS_bak
```

although I wouldn't normally recommend that.

---

As a side note: when working with a format/template string it's usually a good idea to use [here-strings](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/12/31/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/) (so that don't need to escpae quotes inside the strings) and the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0#special-operators) (`-f`):

```
@"
collection1:
{0}
"@ -f ($collection1 | Out-String)
```